# discord.js member.roles.has(Group) - undefined

Tags: discord.js

I want to give GroupID1 to user, who write commnad, but he can not be in GroupID2. When I write command, i got TypeError: Cannot read propety 'has' of undefined.

Code:

```
//GetRole.js
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
   const GroupID1 = ('510537798458146826');
   const GroupID2 = ('510846208911081476');
   const member = message.author;

   if(!member.roles.has(GroupID2)) {
      message.channel.send(member);
      member.addRole(GroupID1).catch(console.error);
   } else {
      message.channel.send('You are alredy in GroupID2');
   }
}
```

I try everything, what i found in another forums, but nothing work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't work because you're defining `member` as `message.author`, but that's a User. Try using:

```
const member = message.member;
```